# Problem of 1 NA result using here.com with Rstudio for routing in Canada

Tags: r, here-routing

I'm using below piece of code in Rstudio to use here.com to obtain in routes in Canada. API results in my df show a combined polygon, distance and duration for a row, but second is all NA. Could you please help me understand, and if possible, fix this issue?

```
# Packages
library("sf")
library("tidyverse")
library( "hereR")
library("stringi") 
library("dplyr")

# Load data
distancePairs <- structure(list(Origin = c("Saskatoon", "St. John's"), Lat1 = c(52.1583630506965, 
47.5535718086621), Lon1 = c(-106.671978365698, -52.7486803304426
), Destination = c("St. John's", "Calgary"), Lat2 = c(47.5535718086621, 
51.0452926068494), Lon2 = c(-52.7486803304426, -114.05905562721
), id = c(17, 18), straight.distance.meters = structure(c(3808910.50512732, 
4332741.9186734), units = structure(list(numerator = "m", denominator = character(0)), class = "symbolic_units"), class = "units")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# Set API key for free through throug https://developer.here.com/self-serve
set_key(api_key = "YOUR_FREEMIUN_KEY") 

# Create SFDFs  (points with lat-lon pairs):
dist.pairs.input.1 <- dist.pairs.query %>%  
  st_as_sf(coords = c("Lon1","Lat1"), 
           crs = "WGS84", 
           remove = F)

dist.pairs.input.2 <- dist.pairs.query %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("Lon2", "Lat2"), 
           crs = "WGS84", 
           remove = F)

#Calculate drive time&distance:
query_result <- route(origin = dist.pairs.input.1, 
                      destination = dist.pairs.input.2,
                      traffic = T)
# Can't dput my answer to share it's structure because it's a huge line that's not fully visible in my console, 
# but result has 3 objets with 13 variables, all id 1, rank 1, section 1-2-3 and it's giving me a summary of 1
query_result2 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2), departure = structure(c(1700159564, 
NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), arrival = structure(c(1700373938, 
NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), type = c("vehicle", 
NA), mode = c("car", NA), distance_km = c(5605.622, NA), duration_min = c(3542.9, 
NA), Origin = c("Saskatoon", "St. John's"), Lat1 = c(52.1583630506965, 
47.5535718086621), Lon1 = c(-106.671978365698, -52.7486803304426
), Destination = c("St. John's", "Calgary"), Lat2 = c(47.5535718086621, 
51.0452926068494), Lon2 = c(-52.7486803304426, -114.05905562721
), straight.distance.meters = structure(c(3808910.50512732, 4332741.9186734
), units = structure(list(numerator = "m", denominator = character(0)), class = "symbolic_units"), class = "units")), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame") # without shp files

result_summary <- query_result %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(new_shp = st_combine(.),
            departure = first(departure),
            arrival = last(arrival),
            type = mode(type),
            mode = mode(mode),
            distance_km = sum(distance)/1000,   
            duration_min = sum(duration)/60)   

# Below snapped result is what I get 
distancePairs$id <- 1:2
result_output<- merge(result_summary,
                      dist.pairs.query,
                      by = "id",
                      all = TRUE)
# Looks like below without geometry, but first one's a MULTILINESTRINGZ and the one that's NA results is a GEOMETRYCOLLECTION Z EMPTY 
result_output2 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2), departure = structure(c(1700159564, 
NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), arrival = structure(c(1700373938, 
NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), type = c("vehicle", 
NA), mode = c("car", NA), distance_km = c(5605.622, NA), duration_min = c(3542.9, 
NA), Origin = c("Saskatoon", "St. John's"), Lat1 = c(52.1583630506965, 
47.5535718086621), Lon1 = c(-106.671978365698, -52.7486803304426
), Destination = c("St. John's", "Calgary"), Lat2 = c(47.5535718086621, 
51.0452926068494), Lon2 = c(-52.7486803304426, -114.05905562721
), straight.distance.meters = structure(c(3808910.50512732, 4332741.9186734
), units = structure(list(numerator = "m", denominator = character(0)), class = "symbolic_units"), class = "units")), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

## Can't dput geometries and be able to copy the full string, so I hope at least this view helps

Comment: Please add the packages you are using to the top of the first code chunk.

Comment: sure Friede, just added! - Didn't mean to exclude that critical piece and I hadn't realized, thanks a ton!

Comment: I think you need to find a way to share the result of `query_result` as text. `dist.pairs.query` is `distancePairs`?

Comment: Sure, just fixed the second point. For the first one I've added it without geometries as those are too long to be able to contain the whole thing in my console